# Dynamically create MySQL table columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following MySQL table which is structured like that:

```
| id | bonus0 |
```

Now I want to add the following data set:

```
| id | bonus0 | bonus1 | bonus2 |  bonus3 |
| 10 |   4582 |  2552  |  8945  |   7564  |
```

As you can see the columns bonus1 - bonus3 aren´t created yet.

How would a php script/ query look like which checks if enough columns are already available and if not which will create the missing ones with consecutive numbers at the end of the word "bonus"?

So in the example the columns bonus1 - bonus3 would be created automatically by the script.

Comment: Don't do this. Instead normalise your schema

Comment: A schema like this is a pretty clear violation of the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). If possible try and restructure this into a one-to-many relational structure as that will make your query almost trivial. You do not want a schema you have to constantly alter to add new data. You *do* want a schema that allows you to trivially add new rows to add new data.

Comment: If you change your table structure to something like this, `id , bonus_id, bonus_value`, your data instead would be like `10, 0, 4582` for `bonus0`, `10, 1, 2552` for `bonus1` and so forth. Then you don't have to worry about creating column when there's a new `bonusX`

Comment: Any time you find yourself manually numbering variables/columns/identifiers like this it's a strong indication that there's a flaw in your design and you should step back and have a fresh look. As others have already suggested, the best approach for this particular issue is to normalize your database schema.

Comment: It's possible to create a JSON field to store arbitrary values, and that's one way this could be resolved, but Zak's answer is the best approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In reality (I mean a normalized relational database) you should have 3 tables.  Lets call them `people`, `bonuses` and `bonus_to_person`

**people** looks like:

```
+-----------------+------------+
|    person_id    |    name    |
+_________________+____________+
|       1         |    john    |
+-----------------+------------+
|       2         |    frank   |
+-----------------+------------+
```

**bonuses** Looks like

```
+----------------+--------------+
|    bonus_id    |    amount    |
+________________+______________+
|       1        |    1000      |
+----------------+--------------+
|       2        |    1150      |
+----------------+--------------+
|       3        |    1200      |
+----------------+--------------+
|       4        |     900      |
+----------------+--------------+
|       5        |     150      |
+----------------+--------------+
|       6        |     200      |
+----------------+--------------+
```

**bonus_to_person** Looks like

```
+----------------+-----------------+
|    bonus_id    |    person_id    |
+________________+_________________+
|       1        |       1         |
+----------------+-----------------+
|       2        |       2         |
+----------------+-----------------+
|       3        |       2         |
+----------------+-----------------+
|       4        |       1         |
+----------------+-----------------+
|       5        |       1         |
+----------------+-----------------+
|       6        |       1         |
+----------------+-----------------+
```

This way, any **ONE** person can have **unlimited bonuses** simply by `INSERTING` into `bonuses` with the amount, and `INSERTING` into `bonus_to_person` with the **bonus_id** and **person_id**

The retrieval of this data would look like

```
SELECT a.name, c.amount from people a
   LEFT JOIN bonus_to_people b
   ON a.person_id = b.person_id
   
   LEFT JOIN bonuses c
   ON c.bonus_id = b.bonus_id

   WHERE a.person.id = 1;
```

Your result from something like this would look like

```
+------------+----+-------+
|    name    |    amount  |
+____________+____________+
|    john    |    1000    |
+------------+------------+
|    john    |    900     |
+------------+------------+
|    john    |    150     |
+------------+------------+
|    john    |    200     |
+------------+------------+
```

You should be using this normalized approach for any database that will continue growing --  Growing "deeper" than "wider" is better in your case ..

Answer (score -2):

```
// Get existing columns of the table
// $queryResult = run SQL query using PDO/mysqli/your favorite thing: SHOW COLUMNS FROM `table`

// Specify wanted columns
$search = ['bonus0', 'bonus1', 'bonus2', 'bonus3'];

// Get just the field names from the resultset
$fields = array_column($queryResult, 'Field');

// Find what's missing
$missing = array_diff($search, $fields);

// Add missing columns to the table
foreach ($missing as $field) {
  // Run SQL query: ALTER TABLE `table` ADD COLUMN $field INT
}
```